# ComboBox in Grid

Tags: javascript, extjs

please help me, how insert **combobox** in field?

```
text: "Combo need is here!!!", width: 100, dataIndex: '', sortable: true
```

here need combobox...

very little material on extjs :(

and one more question, if suitable extjs for the mobile interface?
I have an online store, practical to use extjs mobile interface?

my code:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
  Ext.define('User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
      {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
      {name: 'day', type: 'string'},
      {name: 'time', type: 'string'},
      {name: 'what', type: 'string'},
      {name: 'combo', type: 'string'}
    ]
  });

  var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'User',
    proxy: {
      type: 'ajax',
      url: 't.php',
      reader: {
        type: 'json'
      }
    }
  });

  var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: store,
    columns: [
      {
        text: "Day", flex: 1, dataIndex: 'day', sortable: true
      },
      {
        text: "Time", width: 115, dataIndex: 'time', sortable: true
      },
      {
        text: "sourse", width: 100, dataIndex: 'what', sortable: true
      },
      {
        text: "Combo need is here!!!", width: 100, dataIndex: '', sortable: true // HERE!!!
      }
    ],
    height:700,

    renderTo: 'grid-example'
  });

  store.load();
});
```

Comment: What version of ExtJs are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the CellEditing or RowEditing plugin, and set the editor property of the field to 'combobox'

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/grid/cell-editing.html

You should not use Sencha ExtJS for mobile. Instead, you should use Sencha Touch 2

http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/